# Why do mean value theorems have open interval for differentiablity while closed for continuity?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For mean value theorems like Lagrange's and Rolle's, we have the following conditions:

> For applying mean value theorem to any function $f(x)$ for the domain $[a,b]$ , it should be
>
> (1) continuous in $[a,b]$
>
> (2) differentiable in $(a,b)$

So why is it that for the criteria of differentiablity, we have the open interval ?? Is it possible for a function differentiable in $(a,b)$ and continuous in $[a,b]$ to be non- differentiable at the end points?

Also why is the first statement needed ?? Doesn't the second statement of differentiablity also mean that the function is continuous ??
I'm not very experienced in calculus and still in high-school,  so it might be something too obvious I'm missing , please help :)

Comment: Yes it is possible for a function differentiable in $(a,b)$ and continuous in $[a,b]$ to be non-differentiable at the end points.  With that encouragement, would you care to seek examples on your own?  And in the last paragraph, note that differentiability on the interior interval $(a,b)$ implies continuity there, but fails to imply (one-sided) continuity at the endpoints.  Again, perhaps you will want to think about how weakening the assumptions (removing continuity at the endpoints) opens the door to functions that do not satisfy the MVT.

Comment: While the first part of the question is similar , the "second part" is not in the question. The second tateme t of differentiablity implying the first statement is not addressed there. Why is it then closed as being duplicate ??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For example, the function $\sqrt{x(1-x)}$ is continuous in $[0,1]$ but only differentiable on $(0,1)$.

On the other hand, $1/x$ is differentiable in $(0,\infty)$ but is not continuous at $0$
(even if you define it at $0$).

Answer (score 15):

Here are a couple of examples to think about:

1. $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ on the interval $[0,1]$.  This is continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$, but not differentiable at 0 in any reasonable sense.  Yet the mean value theorem applies to it.
2. $f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x = 0 \\ 1, & x > 0. \end{cases}$ This is differentiable on $(0,1)$ but the mean value theorem does not apply to it.